# Eclipse CDT omits leading dash from -D

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am compiling a .c file with a specified _D option MY_OPT.  In the **properties -> c++ build -> settings -> gcc c compiler -> symbols** I  creqated an entry and put MY_OPT in as the value.

When I compile I get error 127 saying that DMY_OPT cannot be found.  I learned that error 127 means it realy came from bash and, after a bit of thought, I realized that since the dash is not there (as in -DMY_OPT) bash indeed would report that there is no input file named DMY_OPT to be found.

I searched google and stackoverflow and found lots of similar questions, but can't formulate one with narrow enough search terms to fine any remotely related answer, so I hope someone here can help.

NOTE:  I removed the SYMBOL and instead put a -DMY_OPT in the miscellaneous field.  No change (or I am getting the Eclipse Juno bug about not deleting previous errors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this question was the test of the overall command line built by Eclipse.  Mine read

```
${COMMAND ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} } ${FLAGS}
         ^                                                   ^ 
         } accidentally moved to here ---------------------->|
```

I had meant to move ${FLAGS} to the end of the command line but also managed to move the right side } form ${COMMAND}..

**NOTE:** This was done to get the compile command line to look like the linker command line where one should move ${FLAGS} to the end of the line thus putting the list of ".o's" and the "-o xxx" before the "_l's: and "-L's" as is required by some releases of gcc/g++.